# Can a 555 amplify another 555?

Tags: 555

I read an article that claimed it is possible for one 555 to amplify another when they are placed in cascade (serially). We always use transistors for amplification; why would we place a 555 in that position?

Comment: The amplifier in `555` is not really used for "amplification" *per se*. `555` main application is timing circuits (multivibrators and such)

Comment: Can you specify what "amplifying a timer" means?

Comment: I for one, would like to read this article.  Please click the edit link below your question and add a link to this article, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The internals of a 555 consist of a pair of comparators and an S-R flip flop. It doesn't have an 'amplifier' as such.

More about the 555 here: [Astable 555 circuit always on, not oscillating](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572431/astable-555-circuit-always-on-not-oscillating/572438#572438)

Perhaps what you mean is to use multiple 555s to create longer time periods. In theory, you could do that.

(related: [Why isn't my 555 cascading timer working?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426446/why-isnt-my-555-cascading-timer-working))

If that's what you're after, a long binary counter or a microcontroller are better options.

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible, as an NE555 does not amplify, it's not an amplifier.

We would not place a 555 in that position.